# How to set legend position to center in VizFrame column charts in SAP UI5?

Tags: sapui5, abap

I have created a column chart using Vizframe in SAP UI5 using JS View. My requirement is to change the default position of legend from right hand side to the bottom.

I found that "sap.viz.ui5.types.legend.Common_position.bottom" could be used previously but it's deprecated now.

Is there another way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

At present you can do it by changing css, Use this class to do that
.v-m-legends{
}
or change transform property position